# Ada, how to package the Ada code to an independent exe file?

Tags: release, package, exe, ada, gnat

I am use GNAT Programming Studio 2011.

I want to know how package the code to an exe file.
Such as package and release my code to a exe file and could running in other computer which is not install the GPS2011.

Thanks!
Sunny

Comment: I am appreciate for all your help, And how to included shared libraries to my installation package?Use -static? Could you tell me the steps? For example, I had already complier my main.adb and got an main.exe file in my GPS working path. What should I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `-static` to the linker flags. Then all shared libraries will be put into the executable. But don't cry about the size then ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! And could you tell me the steps? About where is the linker flag could add -static? What's the executable? Is it the main file?Sorry, I am a beginner. God Bless You!

Comment: if you use GPS, open the project preferences. there is a tab to the left called "Switches", beneath this there is a tab named "Linker". There you can add the linker flags you want in a textbox.

Answer (score 4):

When you configured GPS for your project, you told it what to call, and where to place, your main program.

That file is your "exe" file (whether it's literally a ".exe" for Windows, or whatever you named it for other Unix-based environments) containing all your code.

If your program employs any *shared* libraries or supporting data or configuration files, the target machine will either have to have those already installed, or they'll need to be included as part of your installation package.

Since you have your "main" exe, this then simply becomes an installation packaging question.  If you're working on Windows, there's a number of Installer utilities available, and for Linux there's various packaging options, like rpm's and deb's.  And there's always the option of simply providing a (compressed) tar file of the execution directory hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks again, and how to included shared libraries to my installation package?Could you tell me the steps? For example, I had already complier my main.adb and got an main.exe file in my GPS working path. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [`GNAT`](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnat/) for development, but [`MinGW`](http://www.mingw.org/) is a usable alternative for preparing `.exe` files.

Addendum: Note that [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) derives from [FSF GNAT](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnat/), and the [GNAT Modified General Public License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT_Modified_General_Public_License) would apply to the distribution of code compiled with [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Before distributing code compiled with GNAT Programming Studio 2011, you should check the license that came with your copy. A related discussion may be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_frm/thread/d0f6c37e3c1b712a).

Comment: No. `MinGW` includes "C, C++, ADA [sic] and Fortran compilers." It also generates `.exe` files.

Comment: The question was about GNAT, not other compilers.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your down-vote, but I believe it is unwarranted. `MinGW` is a convenient way to package code developed with `GNAT`.